# Suppose E is an infinite subset of a metric space X.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that x is a limit point of $E$ if and only if there is a sequence $\left \{ x_n \right \}^\infty_{n=1} \subset E $ that converges to x.

This was part of our practice final and I have no idea how to solve it. I feel like we have to use covers and subcovers, but can anyone help?

Comment: This is false. You need an extra hypothesis to make it correct, such as $x\not\in E$ or $x_n\neq x$ for all $n$.  Counterexample: $E=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ in $\mathbb R$, where $2$ is not a limit point of $E$, but the sequence $(2,2,2,2,\ldots)$ in $E$ converges to $2$.  Regardless, there is no need to use covers or subcovers.

Comment: Could one tell me that What is the definition of limit point?

Comment: A point p is a limit point of the set E if every neighborhood of p contains a point p\neq q where q\in E

Answer (score 0):

A correct statement is that $x$ is a limit point of $E$ iff there is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $E\setminus\{x\}$ that converges to $x$. You should have little difficulty showing that if such a sequence exists, then $x$ is a limit point of $E$; just use the definitions of *limit point* and *limit of a sequence*.

The slightly harder direction is to show that if $x$ is a limit point of $E$, then there is such a sequence. Let $n\in\Bbb N$; since $x$ is a limit point of $E$, there is a point $x_n\in B(x,2^{-n})\cap(E\setminus\{x\})$, i.e., a point of $E$ such that $0<d(x_n,x)<2^{-n}$. Now just show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$.

Note that instead of $2^{-n}$ I could have used any sequence of positive real numbers converging to $0$. That is, if $\langle r_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of positive real numbers, then for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there must be a point $x_n\in B(x,r_n)\cap(E\setminus\{x\})$, and it’s straightforward to show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$, simply using the fact that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $r_n<\epsilon$.

Comment: Would it be correct to say this:
For each positive integer n, there is a point p_{n} \in E, such that d(p_{n},p) < \frac{1}{n} 

Given \epsilon >0, Choose N so that N\epsilon >1. If n>N, it follows that d(p_{n},p) < \epsilon. Hence p_{n} \rightarrow p.

Comment: @user77107: (If you enclose each of the mathematical expressions in single dollar signs, e.g., `$p_{n} \in E$`, they’ll display properly.) Yes, that looks okay.